# Wrong date saving

Tags: php, date

I have a form in which I have integrated calender field :

Publish date and Unpublish date

When I am sbmitting this form I have 
Publish date = 1/18/2017 and unpublish date = 1/19/2017;

In Controller i am making custom time

```
$pubdate =  strtotime("$publish_date 00:00:00");  
$unpdate =  strtotime("$publish_date 23:59:59");
```

In db it's saving wrong date

```
select from_unixtime(publish_date) as a , from_unixtime(unpublish_date) as b from banner ;
```

output :

> '2017-01-18 05:30:00.000000', '2017-01-20 05:29:00.000000'

where I'm doing wrong

Or is there any way to save the time :

Like publish date = `01/18/2017` (m/d/Y) it should become `01/18/2017 00:00:00` and save it in db like : `1551398401`

Comment: Could it be the concatenation? Try this $pubdate =  strtotime($publish_date . " 00:00:00");

Comment: First there is no month 18 or 19, but trying to get Americans to use sensible formatting is probably not part of the question. It can look like you have a timezone +5:30 set in your database but not in php

Comment: @JotaPardo it will give same output

Comment: Show us the code that stores these dates to your database.

Comment: Looks like a TIMEZONE issue to me

Comment: @rypskar The format "month, day, year" exists in American format

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have simple insert query $query = "insert into paras_banner('title_link','publish_date','publish_date') values('title',$pubdate,$unpdate)";

Comment: @leo_ap, yes but it is not a sensible format :P About the actual question, what is your timezone in php and what is the timezone in sql?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Or is there any way to save the time :

Like publish date = 01/18/2017 (m/d/Y) it should become 01/18/2017 00:00:00 and save it in db like : 1551398401

Comment: MYSQL saves Date/Times in UTC/GMT time. If your timezone is +5:30 from UTC this would explain why when you read it back you get this difference

Answer (score 0):

> output :
>
> > '2017-01-18 05:30:00.000000', '2017-01-20 05:29:00.000000'

```
object(DateTime)[2]
  public 'date' => string '2017-01-18 05:30:00.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'UTC' (length=3)
```

This is how it stores in database.
To display this

```
<?php
echo date_format($dbdate, 'd/m/y H:i:s'); //Output: 01/18/2017 00:00:00
?>
```